# Matching CSVs on multiple columns (column don't always match!)

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 csv files with a couple of identifier columns, say 'a', 'b', and 'c'.
The csv have to match on at least 1 column (so not all 3).
I know for certain that at least 1 one of these identifiers matches (I don't know which). Also there are situations where 'a' != 'a' but 'b' == 'b', in this case I still would like the cases to match.

My idea was to add values to one csv file based on these identifier columns by looping through them: so for example if 'a' != 'a' check if 'b' == 'b', then add the columns from the 2nd csv.

It is probably not the most efficient way, but it's the only way I could think of (I'm still quite new to python).

```
df1['var1'] = 0

for index,row in df1.iterrows():
    print(index)
    for index2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
        if df1['a'][index] == df2['a'][index2]:
            df1['var1'] = df2['var1'] #add rest of variables
        elif df1['b'][index] == df2['b'][index2]:
            df1['var1'] = df2['var1'] #add rest of variables
        elif df1['c'][index] == df2['c'][index2]:
        df1['var1'] = df2['var1'] #add rest of variables
        else df1['var1'] = np.nan
```

Sample data

df1

```
a;b;c
GWIMPBWGXFLOXCTMWTQZ;JWRLDDZNSEDQIJWZXUKC;CKKAYMVNTLQHRJMKTGYM
IOUXKHIERLLTIWFZNBOY;LTVJGHXDSQBIISYRUGSB;FWIIEJPSGJIDMBMMHVCC
VDGPMKXPKMQYCFPSPRVV;JODUSSSZMVGJMPNUZZTU;SXMSOPVFRLYBJVYJEIRW
XJLLWPCRPLYAOKWGCNSA;QOABSMYWLCMRZUQETBSW;LTYFHWMKPDPUXJDFXEGE
HKSGVXNGZYCDKIVMHPOQ;TXWBAJZNXCHRNDTOVGSK;SFUIWDVEVBQASJPXGYET
LJHOTWYPZCXJQMJDFBMX;KFTJXNDFDZHLKNHGIBPO;PNEBLKIVUVUKBOLRNJWR
JKYIABDSHIMCFBFKYMHI;FAUMYUUFVVKGIFODYMBM;YKCNNIRFLWDFKXAJBIYB
FGNQDGBIHUQOXHUZFZVG;EKYZSQQDWNABDOMUYBCB;ZCJTLHITYEUIQOAXEMIC
SVZAYRKZKTLCSWLYUTXH;JZMPNGLCCWVZOEQBDCEJ;JGDYBLYRBACDNTHEKJKI
UEEUYZHPMJRPFYPRWLGX;MTJOFRQYEXAQDZFHXMJE;SLEAHIGGOYJKRMDLIYQB
ZILSTFUZVBNQVCQBRLCQ;VLJPEKQTHVYJSSPDCTXO;VEXYZXHKQANMYCSWJCKJ
WFIEQVJAAPBJRLBOFVLM;OHUNXXTJGIVAOQNWUKZV;IYVKLYRFQWKDXEOLYBCU
VGPJZITWIOHVOJGBVKPD;XUOWFMLJZPGXMDICKTRM;DZIAVAPJYOAETIZOGIOV
BBWCSDGLFWPJNGYHJFJY;XWAFMPCGCJLZDDQDKYWJ;ODMXYHHRCIOCTKWUETIG
OXDFCYSCNNOLILXYUBKD;HOKQECAJJTPWWCILRXSR;XWZZKFJXSKUEJRMJNAWW
ZEJZXTIQMKLUGHLHHLXD;GKDGXNGWNPEQBFFISGPM;ZPMKALEPWATAWNEOYXAR
QICFKQZOYPYGQJDUIMSC;YQWKXJXEWMXISJVPRVVV;IIDRIDKDPXTOIMVTBERK
CXJPRVANPQYDERCZIUDB;DQOLCHRUTYZEOJSFQRFN;XVMJLZBHSTOXPIQOOJTM
FTSITDDXKVIEOAOFFDXV;AWPPKQQNVUAHMJICUXVA;BWIXIYBZUGJYBHHAQZWO
QHDUVSQFETFVZJOKNNZV;VJSMCXMOWFKRKXMGAYRI;XJALGABNCZWVKHMXWWCW
```

df2

```
a;b;c;var1
GWIMEEBWGXFLOXCTMWTQZ;;CKKAYMVNTLQHRJMKTGYM;834562
IOUXKHIERLLTIWFZNBOY;LTVJGHXDSQBIISYRUGSB;FWEERRPSGJIDMBMMHVCC;2345658
;JODUSSSZMVGJMPNUZZTU;SXMSOPVFRLYBJVYJEIRW;662453
XJLLWPCRPLYAOKWGCNSA;QOABSMYWLCMRZUQETBSW;;324276
HKSGVXNGZYCDKIVMHPOQ;TXWBAJZNXCHRNDTOVGSK;SFUIWDVEVBQASJPXGYET;1134921
LJHOTWYPZCXJQMJDFBMX;KFTJXNDFDZHLKNHGIBPO;PNEBLKIVUVUKBOLRNJWR;2019234
JKYIABDSHIMCFBFKYMHI;FAUMYUUFVVKGIFODYMBM;YKCNNIRFLWDFKXAJBIYB;9872346
FGNQDGBIHUQOXHUZFZVG;EKYZSQQDWNABDOMUYBCB;ZCJTLHITYEUIQOAXEMIC;7564374
SVZAYRKZKTLCSWLYUTXH;;;2345252
UEEUYZHPMJRPFYPRWLGX;MTJOFRQYEXAQDZFHXMJE;SLEAHIGGOYJKRMDLIYQB;5654632
ZILSTDSDSBNQVCQBRLCQ;;VEXYZXHKQANMYCSWJCKJ;4524234
WFIEQVJAAPBJRLBOFVLM;OHUNXXTJGIVAOQNWUKZV;IYVKLYRFQWKDXEOLYBCU;2423423
VGPJZITWIOHVOJGBVKPD;XUOWFMLJZPGXMDICKTRM;DZIAVAPJYOAETIZOGIOV;3423425
;XWAFREWGCJLZDDQDKYWJ;ODMXYHHRCIOCTKWUETIG;7864375
OXDFCYSCNNOLILXYUBKD;HOKQECAJJTPWWCILRXSR;XWZZKFJXSKUEJRMJNAWW;2132543
ZEJZXTIQMKLUGHLHHLXD;GKDGXNGWNPEQBFFISGPM;ZREWALEPWATAWNEOYXAR;4524235
QICFKQZOYPYGQJDUIMSC;;IIDRIDKDPXTOIMVTBERK;5544332
CXJPRVANPQYDERCZIUDB;DQOLCHRUTYZEOJSFQRFN;XVMJLZBHSTOXPIQOOJTM;9345633
FTSITDDXKVIEWAOFFDXV;AWPPKQQNVUAHMJICUXVA;BWIXIYBZUGJYBHHAQZWO;4213465
QHDUVSQFETFVZJOKNNZV;VJSMCXMOWFKRKXMGAYRI;XJALGABNCZWVKHMXWWCW;2143112
```

I would expect that var1 would contain the values from the second csv (when matched with either 'a', 'b', or 'c') or contain a NaN value when there are no matching identifiers (this shouldn't be the case, but might be in this sample data).

However, there must be something wrong because the code is extremely slow, it takes like 20 secs to iterate through 1 row. The dataset is not huge (599 cases).

There must be an easier and faster way to do this. Can you help me out/point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please add [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MaxIRADS Your current code doesn't run.

Comment: It's slow because the loop isn't doing what you expect. You are constantly setting the **entire** column `df1['var1']` equal to `df2['var2']`. There are ways to do this without a loop, but that requires sample data to test.

Comment: @MaxIRADS your order of operation should be 1) Reset indexes of both df's 2) Merge both dataframes on index 3) Perform a parallel operation that checks for your conditions in 2 rows, and copies into a 3rd: `df1.loc[(df1['a'] == df1['b']),'var1']=df1['b']` - But that's just a general answer. Your solution lies in merging & parallel operations.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your answers. I've edited my post and added some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in your example everything is sorted exactly in the right order, then you could just do:

```
df1['var1'] = df2['var1']
```

Since that is probably not what you mean, here's a solution when the dataframes can not be exactly matched so easily:

**First** merge df1 on column 'a' with df2 column 'a' and 'var1'. This is basically a left join and adds 'var1' if join can be made, otherwise 'nan'.

```
df1_a = df1.merge(df2.loc[df2['a'].notnull(), ['a','var1']], how='left')
```

**Then** do the same again for the other columns, so one time merging on column 'b' and another time on column 'c':

```
df1_b = df1.merge(df2.loc[df2['b'].notnull(), ['b','var1']], how='left')

df1_c = df1.merge(df2.loc[df2['c'].notnull(), ['c','var1']], how='left')
```

**Finally** combine all separate dataframes together, but only if there's a nan in the var column:

```
df1 = df1_a.fillna(df1_b).fillna(df1_c)
df1['var1'] = df1['var1'].astype(int)
```

**Result:**

```
    a   b   c   var1
0   GWIMPBWGXFLOXCTMWTQZ    JWRLDDZNSEDQIJWZXUKC    CKKAYMVNTLQHRJMKTGYM    834562
1   IOUXKHIERLLTIWFZNBOY    LTVJGHXDSQBIISYRUGSB    FWIIEJPSGJIDMBMMHVCC    2345658
2   VDGPMKXPKMQYCFPSPRVV    JODUSSSZMVGJMPNUZZTU    SXMSOPVFRLYBJVYJEIRW    662453
```